Adding example value in the schema of API
I have also enabled the annotations in my Program.cs
namespace INA.FOBO.Domain
{
public class GetDataModelInput
{
///
/// Key id of the model table
/// 
/// 9
[Column("Keyid")]
public int ModelId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Table name of the model
    /// </summary>
    [SwaggerSchema("DML_CustomerCreditLimitExposureHeader")]
    [Column("Tablename")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
}

}

I want the schema to have a attribute example with a value


Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a look at how to ask to improve your question.
